# print text and qr code on thermical printer in Java

Tags: java, printing, qr-code, epson

I will try explain as directly as possible, English is not my first language =).

I have a thermical printer Epson TM-20, I installed it in my pc over USB and I'm able to print a page test from 'Windows > Devices and Printers'. I'm developing a software that print reports on that printer using Java, in this case I have to send the report over windows, it means using the name of the printer, like that:

```
PrintService ps = getPrintService("EPSON TM-T20");
DocPrintJob docPrint = null;
docPrint = ps.createPrintJob();
docPrint.getPrintService();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(stream, flavor, null);
docPrint.print(doc, getAtributoSet());

public static PrintRequestAttributeSet getAtributoSet() {
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT);
    aset.add(new JobName("Report 1", null));
    aset.add(new Copies(1));
    return aset;
}
```

This code works... Then I get a QrCode too, like that:

```
String qrCodeText= "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
int size = 125;
String fileType = "png";
File qrFile = new File(filePath);
createQRImage(qrFile, qrCodeText, size, fileType);
```

After this I have a image "png" in variable qrFile.
I want to print this...
-----------/n
My header/n
Hi I'm here explaining the/n
 
Qr Code below./n
-----------/n
"""Image QRCODE from qrFile"""
-----------/n
My footer/n
Thanks for your help!!/n
-----------/n

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How your method `createQRImage` is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

@AlexR
this one.

```
private static void createQRImage(File qrFile, String qrCodeText, int size,
        String fileType) throws WriterException, IOException {
    // Create the ByteMatrix for the QR-Code that encodes the given String
    Hashtable hintMap = new Hashtable();
    hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
    QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix byteMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(qrCodeText,
            BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, size, size, hintMap);
    // Make the BufferedImage that are to hold the QRCode
    int matrixWidth = byteMatrix.getWidth();
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(matrixWidth, matrixWidth,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    image.createGraphics();

    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, matrixWidth, matrixWidth);
    // Paint and save the image using the ByteMatrix
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixWidth; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixWidth; j++) {
            if (byteMatrix.get(i, j)) {
                graphics.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    ImageIO.write(image, fileType, qrFile);
}
```

Although, I have this one too, to create qrCode:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(urlQrCode).to(ImageType.PNG).withSize(250, 250).stream();
```

The last one I'm using the library qrGen based in zxing...